# The use of existential "there" and an adjective alone

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the 22nd episode of the 9th season of *Friends*, I encountred an unfamiliar grammar structure. Here is the context:

> Monica: Hey guys! Dinner's ready!
>
> Zack: Oh! I'm gonna go wash up first. (Chandler points him the
> bathroom) Thanks!
>
> Chandler: So what do you think? I want that guys genes for my kid!
> Those eyes, those cheeckbones!
>
> Monica: Ok, **there's enthusiastic and there's just plain gay**!!

What does Monica mean by *there's enthusiastic...*? Could you explain the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I'm only explaining the line as it was written and intended. Some people might consider this joke to be outdated and possibly even offensive nowadays.

Sometimes we use "*there's [x], and then there's [y]*" to mean that two things have a *similar quality but to a massively different degree*. For example, "*there's beautiful and then there's you*" would be a way of saying someone was *extremely* beautiful. Other times we may use the same construction in a *sarcastic* way to say that two things are *not* alike. For example, if someone said someone was "nice" you could counter that by saying "*there's nice, and then there's [name]*", which would sarcastically mean that the person is *not* nice.

In your example, it seems to be the former - showing that something is many degrees greater than the other. There exists a *stereotype* (possibly offensive to some) that gay (homosexual) men are *flamboyant*. In your example, Chandler is talking about another man's (Zack's) physical features in an over-enthusiastic way. Monica is suggesting that Chandler's enthusiasm for Zack is so exaggerated he is appearing as if he might be attracted to him, hence 'gay'.